# Is it possible to boot from a healthy SSHD salvaged from a different laptop

Tags: windows, boot, bios, hybrid-storage

I have an SSHD that I removed from an older laptop I am positive that the drive is OK and not corrupted what so ever. the reason I removed it was that the old laptop's GPU burnt and is no longer usable.
[SSHD GPT protective partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umWZX.png)

Now I want to access the data in the sshd it as if it was never removed from the old laptop.
Is it possible to force the bios to load from the salvaged sshd that is now connected via USB ?

I working with windows OS, the older laptop had Windows 8.1 , the current one has Windows 10.

UPDATE:  the SSHD at this point is connected to the new laptop via USB

Comment: Probably not. Even if your BIOS will let you start booting it and if there are no geometry differences, Windows is extremely picky about drivers, so unless the hardware is extremely similar Windows wont load.

Comment: @davidgo That was the case with XP, but since Vista things were improving with each new version and Windows 10 is already tolerating hardware changes pretty well.

Comment: Can you not access your data after connecting in by USB ?

Comment: The only safe way: Get a USB "cabinet" for the old drive (preferably USB3+ for speed) and copy files off the disk. With the data off, reformat the disk and reuse.

Comment: I once took out a HDD from HP laptop and put it inside a toshiba laptop and it booted normally no issues (windows 7)

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for:
https://winaero.com/blog/boot-usb-drive-windows-10/

Comment: I figured maybe if I boot from the drive I could then make a copy of all the data on it.

Comment: You are mixing up your terms. The BIOS shouldn't be touched, as it is really part of the hardware. Booting Windows from the disk is another matter entirely, and can be done from the boot menu of your *current BIOS* if you connect the disk as internal inside the computer. Success is not guaranteed since device drivers may be missing.

Comment: When I mentioned the BIOS, I as referring to editing the booting drive maybe I didn't explain myself properly

Comment: @Hannu I am unable to access the data windows is seeing it as GPT protective partition, I could clean the disk but I want my data intact, I am not sure how to copy the data since windows is not letting me access it in the first place.

Comment: PASS on the GPT stuff; I avoid the use of that just because of this issue. This is a benefit ONLY if **somebody else** is trying to get access you your data. The downside is that you yourself is locked out in the same way.

Comment: @Hannu I am not sure what to do at this point

Comment: @gronostaj Thats not been my experience - indeed people have been trying to minimize the problem by using "sysprep" for ages.

Comment: Was 8.1 the OEM-installed version, or did you upgrade to it from Win 7?  If it was OEM, both drives should be set up for UEFI, so that's one less hurdle.  If 8.1 was an upgrade from Win 7, the drive probably isn't set up to boot on a UEFI system.  To boot it, you would need to change that setting in the system.  But if you only want to extract files from it, there's no need to boot that drive.  Just use an external USB enclosure or adapter and plug it in as an external drive after you boot normally.

Comment: @fixer1234 I installed Windows 8.1 did not upgrade from 7  ,
The drive is connected via USB , I am unable to access the data (GPT protective parition) issue , I am unable to boot via USB since it not being recognized as a bootable device

Comment: Just for clarification, laptops typically come with an installed OS.  If you installed 8.1, that suggests that there was already something there.  Laptops prior to Win 8 did not have UEFI, so if you installed 8.1 on such a laptop, that drive would not be configured to boot with UEFI on a Win 10 computer (assuming Win 10 is the OEM OS or was installed on a recent machine).  The point is that if you want to boot the drive, no matter how it's connected, it won't be bootable unless its boot provision was configured for the same mode as the Win 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

First lets us set the goal, we have two options:

1. I want to boot the old disk.
2. I want to rescue the data.

Booting the old disk is tricky, unless you have a [nearly] identical laptop.  There are ways around thise, but many of those involve making changes to the setup on the old disk **before** moving it over.

Added to that booting it as a second disk rather then just replacing the current internal disk add complications. And it might be even harder if one uses BIOS (the old firmware, no longer used these days), or UEFI (new firmware).

As I read the main goal of the question to be the to rescue the data, I will just focus on that.  One luckily that might be trivial if you did not enable bitlocked or any other encryption.  Just place the drive in an external USB caddy, plug it in and access the data.

Note: this assumes no full disk encryption. If there is please edit your question to add this relevant data.

Comment: The disk was not encrypted, I did connect it via an external USB , as you see in the image attached, windows doesn't allow me to access the data as it's GPT protective type.

Comment: @user2976492 Did you clear the GPT Protective partition ??
https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/gpt-protective-partition.html

Comment: @Elmo No, don't want to clean the drive and then recover the data. I am not willing to take such risk with my data.

Comment: Hmm, so the data is there. But your rescue OS looks at the MBR protective fake entry ather than using proper EUFI/GPT?  I sthe system use to rescues 6+ years old (or rather in BIOS mode rather then regular UEFI mode) ?

Answer (score -2):

https://m.wikihow.com/Boot-from-an-External-Hard-Drive
Check how to boot an OS installed on an external HDD
Read Part Two of Three.
Connect your SSHD

- Restart your PC
- Keep pressing BIOS key
- Find Boot order
- Move the hard drive to the top of the list
- Save changes and exit BIOS
- Once your external hard drive is selected as the boot location, your boot program or service will open; follow the on-screen prompts to open, install, or set up the program or service.
  If you already have an operating system installed and set up on the external hard drive, completing the BIOS setup will open the operating system.

Comment: Please include essential instructions in your answer and provide the link as a source. Otherwise if the link dies, your answer will become worthless.

Comment: I would have to copy all the steps in the link and post here !! The description "how to boot an OS installed on an external HDD" can be googled in case this  particular link dies

Comment: The linked info seems to suggest to *reformat the drive* for use. Not what OP wants.

Comment: @Hannu : Part Two of Three does not...edited my answer.

Comment: can the down-votes be undone now ?

Comment: I was thinking of doing the steps you described Emiley , I will upvoate if it works , thank you.

Comment: I've attempted to choose a USB booting method, however the drive is no being recognized as a bootable device.

Comment: @user2976492 did it work ?

Comment: @Elmo No, it did not , the usb is not being recognized as a bootable device